# AWS Polly Policy json for polly:SynthesizeSpeech IAM

Tags: amazon-polly, aws-policies

I am trying to set up the proper policy json for IAM programmatic access, but the following runs into the below error ... I have tried it also without sid and with Resource as an array.

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": 
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "AllowAllPollyActions",
            "Action": [
                "polly:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }}
```

`is not authorized to perform: polly:SynthesizeSpeech with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy`